# Diophantine word problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A farmer purchased $100$ head of livestock for a total cost of $4000$. Prices were as follows: calves, $120$ each; lambs, $50$ each; piglets, $25$ each. If the farmer bought at least one animal of each type, how many of each did he buy? (Give all possible solutions.)

Can someone come up with the diophantine equation to get me started? I'm just a little confused because I have the total number and total cost...

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go about solving the problem:

**Step 1 - Equations:**

$C + L + P = 100 \tag{1}$
$120 \cdot C + 50 \cdot L + 25 \cdot P = 4000 \tag{2}$

where $C, L, P$ are the number of Calves, Lambs and Pigs respectively.

Solving for $C$ and $L$ (in terms of $P$)$^1$ tells us that *all* possible solutions will be of the form $(C, L, P) = \left(\frac{5P - 200}{14}, \frac{1600-19P}{14}, P\right) \tag{3}$

**Step 2 - Constraints:** These will put a restriction on the values $P$ can take, and thus on the possible solutions represented by $(3)$.
$C, L, P \ge 1 \tag{A}$
$C, L, P \in \mathbb{Z} \tag{B}$

From $(A)$ we get the first set of restrictions:

$\begin{matrix} & \frac{5P - 200}{14} \ge 1, & \frac{1600-19P}{14} \ge 1, & P \ge 1 \\ \implies & P \ge 42.8, & P \le 83.47, & P \ge 1 \end{matrix}$

$\therefore P \in [42.8, 83.47] \tag{4}$

From $(B)$ we get the second set of restrictions:

$\begin{matrix} & \frac{5P - 200}{14} = k_1, & \frac{1600-19P}{14} = k_2, & P \in \mathbb{Z} \\ \implies & P = 14\left(\frac{k_1}{5}\right) + 40, & \text{redundant}, & P \in \mathbb{Z} \end{matrix}$

$\therefore P = 14k + 40 \tag{5}$

where $k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k = (k_1 / 5) \in \mathbb{Z}$ so as to satisfy $P \in \mathbb{Z}$. Notice that I marked the integer constraint on $L$ as redundant, since it automatically follows from $(1)$ if $C, P$ are integers.

Combining $(4) \text{ and } (5)$ gives $P \in \{54, 68, 82 \} \tag{6}$

**Step 3 - Solutions:** Substituting into $(3)$ gives us *all* possible solutions.

$$\begin{matrix}C & L & \color{#000080}{P} \\ 5 & 41 & \color{#000080}{54} \\ 10 & 22 & \color{#000080}{68} \\ 15 & 3 & \color{#000080}{82}\end{matrix}$$

$^1$Note you can also solve for $L, P$ in terms of $C$ or $C, P$ in terms of $L$ and follow a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose he bought C calves, L lambs, and P piglets.

Then we would have:
$$C+L+P=100$$
$$120C+50L+25P=4000$$
$$C,L,P \ge 1$$

Substitute the 1st equation in the 2nd to find the equation to solve.

Comment: how do I substitute c+l+p=100 into the second equation when the price of each animal is being multiplied by the variable?

Comment: The first equation can be written as $P=100-C-L$. Substitute to find $120C+50L+25(100-C-L)=4000$. That leaves us with $95C+25L=1500$.

Comment: This might be a lot to ask but is there any way you can check your solution.. I got that there can be 5 calves, 41 lambs, 54 pigs and 10 calves, 22 lambs, 68 pigs..but I am not sure if these are all the solutions.

Comment: When I plugged my one solution into the formulas to get all the solutions I wasn't sure if I set that equation to just a greater than inequality or greater than or equal to

Comment: I'm afraid you do not have all solutions yet, but the ones you have are correct. You can simplify $95C+25L=1500$ to $19C+5L=300$. When you have one solution, you can add 5 calves and subtract 19 lambs to find another solution. Repeating that gives you all solutions. And of course you need to check if the final C,L,P are all at least 1.

Comment: how many solutions are there total? Do you think my mistake is setting -300+5t>0 and 1200-19t>0 instead of > or equal to?

Comment: The mistake is not related to $>$ or $\ge$. Where's your confusion with those? It is either $>0$ or $\ge 1$. To find another solution, suppose you add another 5 calves and subtract 19 lambs...

Comment: why we must add 5 calves and subtract 19 lambs to find another answwer?how you get the answer?please help me.

Comment: i got gcd 5..i dont know how to plug in in equation 19C + 25L = 1500..can you explain how you get 5calves 41 lamb and 54piglets and 10 calves 22 lambs and 68 pigs?